# A point $x$ in topological space $X$ is called accumulation point fo a set $ A \subset X$ if $ x \in ‎\overline{A - \{x\}} $.

Tags: general-topology

A point $x$ in topological space $X$ is called accumulation point fo a set $ A \subset X$ if $ x \in ‎\overline{A - \{x\}} $.

Are for a $T_1$ topological space $X$ the following equivalent? why?

> (1) every infinite subset of $X$ has an accumulation point.
>
> (2) every sequence in $X$ has a cluster point.
>
> **Does the scond condition imply countably compact of $X$**?

Comment: Your definition is misstated. What is the role of the set $A$?

Comment: @UmbertoP. I corrected it.

Comment: What are your thoughts? Can you tell if there is an implication in at least one direction?

Comment: The problem states that in a $T_1$-space the properties *countably compact* and *weakly countably compact* are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

$(2) \Rightarrow (1)$ :
Let $A$ be an infinite subset of $X$ and $(x_n)$ an injective sequence of $A$ (which exists because $A$ is infinite). Let $\alpha$ be a cluster point of $(x_n)$. The injectivity of $(x_n)$ implies that it exists a rank $n_0$ such as $\forall n > n_0, x_n \neq \alpha$. So $\alpha \in \overline{\{x_n | n > n_0\}}$ and then $\alpha \in \overline{A - \{\alpha\}}$.

$(1) \Rightarrow (2)$ :
Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence of $X$.
If $A = \{x_n|n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is finite, $(x_n)$ has obviously a cluster point.
Otherwise, $A$ has an accumulation point $\alpha$. $X$ is T1 so every neighbourhood $U$ of $\alpha$ contains an infinity of points of $A$ and so for all $n_0$, it exists $n > n_0$ such as $x_n \in U$.

Comment: This shows that each neighborhood $U$ of $\alpha$ contains infinitely many $x_n$, which means that $\alpha$ is a cluster point of $(x_n).$ It is not always possible to build a subsequence of $(x_n)$ converging to $\alpha,$  this works only in first-countable spaces.

Comment: Indeed... I'll fetch a more general solution. (or a counter example)

Comment: But you don't need the converging subsequence. $\alpha $ is a cluster point of $(x_n)$ if for each nbh $U$ of $\alpha$ and for each $n_0\in\Bbb N$ there is an $n>n_0$ such that $x_n\in U.$ (In other words $U$ contains infinitely many - not necessarily distinct - $x_n$).

Comment: Does the sconde condition imply countably compact of $X$?

Comment: @Stefan H. Thanks. I based my thoughs on a wrong definition of cluster point.

Comment: Now, your answer looks quite good :-)